# How to exit early from a Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have to exit from my Python code if the reservation which I mentioned in code already exits. I'm trying with below code, but it is not working:

```
res_api = ReservationServiceClient()
if res_api.get_reservation(name=myreservation):
    sys.exit(0)
else:
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just `return` to exit early from a Cloud Function:

```py
res_api = ReservationServiceClient()
if res_api.get_reservation(name=myreservation):
    return 'OK'
```

Do not use `sys.exit(O)` as this will prevent the request from being completed.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what `ReservationServiceClient` and `res_api.get_reservation`, you need to create a new question with more detail.